# How to hide manifest variables, so that it is less exposed?

Tags: spring, properties, manifest, cloud-foundry

I am storing my oauth credentials in env variables on Cloud Foundry. Server I am using is TomCat. How can I mask my env varibles in my manifest file so that, My clientId and secrets will not be exposed? I've seen examples where users use property placeholders.

```
 spring:
    profiles:
      active: dev
    thymeleaf:
      prefix: classpath:/templates/
      suffix: .html
      mode: HTML5
      encoding: UTF-8
      content-type: text/html
      cache: true

  env:        
    accessTokenUri: https://mytokenURI
    apiUrl: https://apiUrls/
    clientId: someID
    clientSecret: NotTellingYou
    scope: scope
```

**Attempt**

In my system environment variables I added the key "accessTokenUri" and the value.

```
 env:        
   accessTokenUri: ${accessTokenUri}
   apiUrl: https://apiUrls/
   clientId: someID
   clientSecret: NotTellingYou
   scope: scope

//output
Property '${accessTokenUri}' found in manifest. This feature is no longer supported. Please remove it and try again.
```

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: I am deploying this onto cloud foundry, with tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JBoss, you can use Jboss vault.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Security_Guide/Configure_the_Enterprise_Application_Platform_to_Use_the_Password_Vault1.html

If you are using tomcat, you can try JCE.
https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/03/04/encrypting-and-decrypting-configuration-property-values-in-spring-cloud/

Comment: Encrypting is a nice way to do it. I guess using property placeholders is not possible?